# Qual a diferença entre JOIN e UNION no SQL?

Tags: sql, join, union

Qual é a diferença entre `JOIN` e `UNION` no SQL? Eu achei que uma query feita com qualquer um dos dois resultaria em uma mesma tabela, mas estou fazendo um curso no DataCamp em que o professor diz que essas duas cláusulas não fazem exatamente a mesma coisa.

Como os JOINs são explicados usando o diagrama de Venn, eu pensei que por exemplo um `FULL JOIN` faria o mesmo que a cláusula `UNION` ou mesmo a cláusla `INETERSECT` faria o mesmo que a cláusula `INNER JOIN`.

Existe mesmo uma diferença nos resultados de uma query usando um ou outro?

Comment: O resultado de um `JOIN` é **uma** linha contendo os campos selecionados das tabelas envolvidas. O resultado de um `UNION` é um **conjunto** de linhas cada uma proveniente de uma das tabelas envolvidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` é usado para ligar tabelas através de um valor em comum.
`UNION` é usado para juntar duas ou mais queries e trazar o resultado todo junto

Sim, os resultados são bem diferentes, o objetivo de um é relacionar as tabelas, o outro juntar resultados.

Veja esse exemplo: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d058/6)

Se apenas fizer `UNION` sem relacionar as tabelas vai ter um resultado cartesiano, ou seja, cada item de cada tabela x cada item da outra, o que é diferente do resultado de um `JOIN`